# btn label for btn-check not changing color immediately on 'uncheck' - touchscreen issue

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am trying to use bootstrap's checkbox buttons - specifically [outline styles explained here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/checks-radios/#outlined-styles).

The problem I am having is most relevant to touch screens.  The problem is when a 'checked' button is touched to 'uncheck' it, it will not appear to 'uncheck' or turn off until **after** the user has touched somewhere else on the screen - which is causing confusion to users who expect an immediate color change.

I am not sure if there is something I am missing in my implementation.  I would value any feedback.

Here is the html that my code generates (just showing 2 button to keep it concise):

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap gap-2 container text-center" id="learnerCheckboxes" tabindex="2">
  <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="box0" autocomplete="off" value="lnr009">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" for="box0">Ari</label>

  <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="box1" autocomplete="off" value="lnr001">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" for="box1">David</label>
</div>
```

I had expected that when a checkbox button that has already been touched is touched again that it will immediately change color.  However, it only does so when the user touches another part of the screen.  This can be confusing for users.

If I use .btn-primary instead, I can see there is a slight change in color when a checked button is touched, but it is barely perceptible.

Comment: Update: I suspected originally that it the button not changing colour on a touch may be due to the hover or active states being 'stuck' on a touch screen - unlike a mouse moving, there is no input to the browser after a touch has happened that the user has moved on...

I added background-color for :hover and :active states. The button's change color, then flick back almost instantly - until the user touches somewhere else on the screen.  So still not ideal.

Also - Is there somethign wrong with the question?  Got down voted but not sure why.  Constructive feedback is very welcome :-)